# How to convert Stream of Maps into a single Map

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, java-stream

I need to use streams to convert the `Stream<Map<EntityType, Set<String>>>` to `Map<EntityType, Set<String>>`.

The `EntityType` is an **`enum`** having certain values, let's say `A`, `B` and `C`. And there are lots of maps in the stream.

I want to concatenate all of them into **one map** using *Stream API*. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<EntityType, Set<String>> mapA = Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("1", "2", "3"), EntityType.B, Set.of("4", "5", "6"));
    Map<EntityType, Set<String>> mapB = Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("1", "4", "5"), EntityType.C, Set.of("4", "5", "6"));
    Map<EntityType, Set<String>> mapC = Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("3", "7", "5"), EntityType.B, Set.of("4", "9", "6"));
    
    // The stream calls you can try:
    Map<EntityType, Set<String>> result = Stream.of(mapA, mapB, mapC)
      .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyValuePair -> keyValuePair.getKey(),
                                keyValuePair -> keyValuePair.getValue(),
                                (value1, value2) -> combine(value1, value2)));
}

private static <T> Set<T> combine(Set<T>... sets) {
    return Stream.of(sets)
      .flatMap(Set::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

enum EntityType {
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

Comment: it is giving compiler warning have to use safeVarArgs is there any way you can avoid using varags in your code?

Comment: @Ankur of course we can avoid using varargs. Just replace it with two arguments `combine(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB)` and then inside the method body change the first line to the following: `return Stream.of(setA, setB)` and let the other two lines untouched.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can *flatten* the **maps** in the stream by applying `flatMap()`. And wrap each **entry** with a *new* one. This step is required **1.** to avoid *mutation* of the source and **2.** to prevent an `UnsupportedOperationException` which will be raised if **sets** are *unmodifiable*.

And then apply `collect()`.

Since `EntityType` is an `enum` the most appropriate choice for the container provided by the `supplier` will be an `EnumMap` which was designed specifically for *enum-keys* and has a better performance than `HashMap`.

Inside the `combine` method `merge()` is being applied on the  *resulting map* to add entries from the stream into it.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>, U> Map<T, Set<U>> collect(Stream<Map<T, Set<U>>> source,
                                                            Class<T> enumClass) {
    return source
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), new HashSet<>(entry.getValue()))))
            .collect(() -> new EnumMap<>(enumClass),
                    (map, entry) -> map.merge(entry.getKey(),
                                              entry.getValue(),
                                              (v1, v2) -> {v1.addAll(v2); return v1;}),
                    Map::putAll);
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Map<EntityType, Set<String>>> source =
            Stream.of(Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("foo"), EntityType.B, Set.of("bar")),
                    Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("foo", "bar"), EntityType.B, Set.of("bar", "fiz")),
                    Map.of(EntityType.A, Set.of("foobar"), EntityType.B, Set.of("abc", "www")));

    System.out.println(collect(source, EntityType.class));
}
```

**Output**

```
{A=[bar, foobar, foo], B=[bar, abc, fiz, www]}
```